# After upgrade version got elastic search error

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5, version-upgrade

I just upgraded my Magento version to the latest Magento version 2.4.5. after a successful upgrade, while I am trying to run di: compile command then I got an error.
how to fix below error.
[image]

Comment: From which version you have upgraded to M 2.4.5? And is your elastic search version matches M2.4.5 requirements

Answer (score 0):

Hope you remove all modules from the vendor folder before updating to M2.4.5 Make sure no files are hanging in IDE or Docker sync if yes this might help:

rm -rf vendor/* && composer update/install.